# Flattened jsonb vs Nested jsonb Performance Postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Flattened:

```
{key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3}
```

vs. Nested:

```
{id1:{key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3},id2:{}}
```

In the flattened version I would store multiple rows and have to group it, in the nested version all the data would be in one row.

Which way would be faster and is it a huge difference?

Comment: The answer may change when 9.4beta3 comes out, as it uses a new on-disk format for `jsonb`. I suggest grabbing the current git master, compiling it, and doing some benchmarking. The testing would currently be really useful; post your results to the pgsql-hackers mailing list. It'll depend partly on what operations you're performing on the json.